# Jenkins groovy not able to clone gitlab repo using oauth token over https port

Tags: jenkins, groovy, oauth-2.0, gitlab, jenkins-groovy

I am Unable to checkout code from gitlab via jenkins groovy using oauth2 token over https.

Cloning works on git cli using the same oauth token. 
I am also able to list all my Gitlab projects via curl on the same machine.

But unable able to invoke git clone using Oauth2 tokens via the groovy pipeline.

Constraints : Jenkins server needs to communicate over https port (only) with gitlab server using oauth2 token via groovy script. I want to use the jenkins credential manager to store the Oauth2 token - instead of passing it directly via s script

Error : status code 128: stderr: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied

**Groovy code used to checkout **

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: "*/$GIT_BRANCH"]], doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [], gitTool: 'Default', submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: "$GIT_CREDS_ID", url: "$GIT_URL"]]])
```

The problem is $GIT_CREDS_ID : is picking only credential ids having the SSH private key or username / password combinations. But does NOT pick the credential id having Oauth token (created post installing git lab plugin)

Error :

```
Warning: CredentialId "2002" could not be found. # same is being listed under jenkins credentials
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
...
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://git.my-gitlab-site.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://git.my-gitlab-site.git/'
```

The same oauth token works fine via curl , git cli and even if i pass it directly in the https url of git like :
https://oauth2:SomeDummyToken@git.aa.st/c-swajai/poc_devops_coe.git

But not able use the same via Jenkins.

**System details**
Jenkins ver. 2.172

OS "Amazon Linux"
VERSION "2"

Found a related bug :
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36863

Comment: did u try pipeline syntax where you can generate code for git checkout and credentials passing via Oath ?

Comment: @MonisMajeed : the git clone command i have mentioned in the question  is generated by pipeline syntax generator. I could not find any option to pass oauth token via groovy script. Only valid entries are credential ids which are already present in jenkins (excluding the ones for oauth tokens )

Answer (score 7):

I found a related [oldbug](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-36863) (status : resolved) which seems to have resurfaced in latest version of jenkins.
A **workaround** for others facing similar issue.

Create new credentials of **type username & password**

Username : AnyRandomString
**Password : YourOauthToken**
Credential id : any custom number / string

Use the above credential id in the groovy script while cloning.
Now you can clone git using https url on 443 port using Oauth tokem

Comment: @MonisMajeed : thanks. i misinterpreted your initial response.

Comment: it worked, I don't know how.